# Cron job email is not being sent

Tags: java, xml, jsp, google-app-engine, cron

So currently I set up my crone job where I want it to send an email at 5pm CDT and I've tested it with every 5 minutes, which seemed to work. I also double checked to see if the email would send properly by manually triggering Cron, which send the email. However, I am not getting any email at 5pm and I'm wondering if my format is wrong? Please help

```
<cronentries>
    <cron>
        <url>/cron</url>
        <description>Daily Digest at 5pm</description>
        <schedule>every day 17:00</schedule>
        <timezone>America/Winnipeg</timezone>
    </cron>
</cronentries>
```

*edit: typo on description and missing schedule (which has been there in my code*

Comment: Does `<description>` control "when it I send"?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you have an extra "descritpion" that should not be a problem, but maybe it is missing some tags such as "schedule" tags. Please try to build your code following the example below, and let us know if it is works for you.

```
<cronentries>
  <cron>
    <url>/cron</url>
    <target>beta</target>
    <description>daily summary job</description>
    <schedule>every 24 hours</schedule>
  </cron>
</cronentries>
```

you can also check the docs regarding cron jobs[1].
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/cron#creating_a_cron_job

Comment: sorry, I just edited the post to include <schedule> tag because for some reason I forgot to put them on the question, but yes I did put the schedule tag in my xml